# No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton' when project build target is set to "Amazon Fire Phone SDK Addon"

Tags: android, android-appcompat, amazon-fire-os

I'm creating app for Amazon store, I already have my same app published in Google Play Store. Now for Amazon devices we have to use project build target as "Amazon Fire Phone SDK Addon" which is build on Android 4.2.2 version. When I use this build target i'm getting following errors :

```
appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'
appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:84: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
.
.
.
MyApp\res\values-v21\styles.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowSharedElementExitTransition'.
```

Last line of error refers to  my app's "values-21" file where i'm using v-21 attributes.

How can I can resolve this issue? I cannot set my build target to 21 or higher because I have to compile with this Amazon fire sdk and I have to use v-21 appcompat for my app to work. So is it even possible to do so ? Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: "Now for Amazon devices we have to use project build target as "Amazon Fire Phone SDK Addon" " -- AFAIK, this is only needed if you are attempting to use Fire Phone-specific APIs. This is not needed to distribute apps through the Amazon AppStore for Android in general. And, since the number of Fire Phone sold seems to be rather low, I am not sure why you would be looking to use Fire Phone-specific APIs.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have to use Amazon's In App purchase API in my app,  so I require to compile it with Amazon Fire Phone SDK, In Google Play store I have implemented Google In-app purchase which will not work in amazon store.

Comment: Amazon's [instructions for integrating with their IAP](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs-v2/getting-started-with-iap-v2.0) does not mention the Fire Phone SDK. No particular build target is required.

Comment: @CommonsWare so sorry for my misunderstanding in going through docs , reading too many docs  randomly confused me, thank you very much for your great help ,you saved my life :) this solves my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fire Phone SDK Addon should only be needed if you are trying to compile against Amazon's proprietary APIs unique to the Fire Phone. Other things related to Amazon, such as [the in-app purchasing APIs for the Amazon AppStore for Android](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs-v2/getting-started-with-iap-v2.0), should not require this add-on.